# I need help with disk partition

Tags: partitioning, disk-management

I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 on a machine running Windows 7 Starter. While installing, I chose the 30 GB installation option which seemed like the largest installation offered. I am unable to use the other 250 odd GB on my hard drive.

I am aware of Disk Utility available through the Dash Home, but unsure how to use it. I am also unable to find/create a mount point for the Windows network accessible through the home folder.

I'd like to continue running Windows, but apportion no more than 50 GB of space and use the rest for Ubuntu. I'm using a Toshiba NB520 netbook.

Can someone help?

---

/dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes Disk identifier: 0xe7763813 Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System /dev/sda1 * 2048 3074047 1536000 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE

/dev/sda2 3074048 609882111 303404032 7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT /dev/sda3 609882112 625141759 7629824 17 Hidden HPFS/NTFS

Comment: can you please open a terminal, and post the output of the command `sudo fdisk -l`?

Comment: Have u installed it via Wuby- Windows installer for Ubuntu.?

Answer (score 2):

`wubi` has a 30Gb limit. Wubi is for those Windows users that want to test Ubuntu without having to add partitions and possibly then just delete it. It is meant as an extended test over just using liveCD, but not for a long term install.

---

You  need to free up those 200Gb you want by creating a new partition (partition magic can do this from within Windows but Linux' gParted can do this too). And you can also remove the wubi install to free up the extra 30Gb. After you got the extra partition you can use a live CD to install Ubuntu in the empty space (the installer will ask for several installation methods including the option to use free space).

Comment: Adempewolff reply:     Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xe7763813

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     3074047     1536000   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2         3074048   609882111   303404032    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       609882112   625141759     7629824   17  Hidden HPFS/NTFS

Comment: Vinit reply: I believe it is a wubi install.

Comment: Rinzwind: can i maintain the dual boot? OR how does your solution affect the dual boot?

Comment: It does not affect dual boot. From what I saw you need to shrink Win to 50 Gb and want the rest for Ubuntu.